# Reset EXM 9.0.2 to its OOTB state

Tags: exm

I've started work on a site that is being upgraded from 8.1.1 -> 9.0.2 and I need to implement some EXM templates. It looks like during the initial content migration process the OOTB 9.0.2 EXM content was overwritten. This includes content from both Core and Master. In Core the Application definition and the Dictionary entries are missing, in Master the Marketing Control Panel Dimentions are missing. I tried to create a package of EXM files and content from a clean 9.0.2 instance in order to install into the migrated site. 
After installing the package, the EXM dashboard is mostly working but the dictionary that are called by js (sitecore.Resources.Dictionary.translate()) do not work. They are present in the Core database. Indexes have been rebuilt.

[image: EXM Dashboard]

The files that I included in the package are:

- /sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/*/**
- /App_Config/Sitecore/EmailExperience/*/**

The items are:

- /master/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Dimensions/ExM/*/**
- /master/sitecore/templates/System/Email/*/**
- /master/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Email/*/**
- /core/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/*/**
- /core/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/EXM/*/**
- /core/sitecore/system/Dictionary/ECM/*/**

Am I missing anything? How do I get the dictionary entries to work correctly?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. It's just as much about removing old items as adding / updating changed ones. You're better off restoring a clean 9.0.2 core and master database and transferring what you need to that.

Comment: @MarkGibbons, I'm leaning towards that as well. I was hoping to avoid it due to time constraints. If there is no other way, then that's what I'll recommend we do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use Mark Gibbons' suggestion of using a clean database importing our changes into it selectively. I used Razl's Deep Compare feature to find custom items that didn't exist in the OOTB databases and a little bit of manual cleanup to get things situated.

Users and Roles were migrated via Serialization. Passwords were migrated using the admin tool here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/242631.